# Redis - Get values inside a dict HMGET

Tags: python, redis

I've created a key in the redis as following:-

```
In [1]: import redis

In [2]: conn = redis.Redis('localhost')

In [3]: user = {
   ...:         'name': 'username',
   ...:         'age': 25,
   ...:         'likes': ['football', 'swimming'],
   ...:         'response': {
   ...:                 'a': 1,
   ...:                 'b': 2
   ...:         }
   ...: }

In [4]: conn.hmset("pythonDict", user)
Out[4]: True

In [5]: conn.hgetall("pythonDict")
Out[5]: 
{'age': '25',
 'likes': "['football', 'swimming']",
 'name': 'username',
 'response': "{'a': 1, 'b': 2}"
}
```

So, now I want to get the values of `name`, `age` etc.

I did the following:-

```
In [9]: conn.hmget("pythonDict","age", "likes")
Out[9]: ['25', "['football', 'swimming']"]
```

Working as expected.

Now I'm stuck at a point where I want to get the value of `a` inside response. How can I directly get the value of `response[a]`, without iterating over it, ie not at the application level???

Answer (score 0):

Redis does not support nested data structures in hashes. Your client has encoded them (`likes` and `response`) as strings (probably using `repr()`, but perhaps JSON), and `hgetall()` returns them as strings.

So there is no Redis command that is going to get you the value of `a`. However, you could explicitly encode the nested data structures as JSON and then write a simple [Lua script](http://redis.io/commands/eval) to extract the value on the server. You would use the included [JSON library](http://redis.io/commands/eval#cjson) to unpack `response` and return the value of `a`.

Comment: --- `Your client seems to have encoded them (likes and response) as JSON strings, and hgetall() returns them as strings.` Its the default behaviour of redis. Treats every value of hash key as string.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast: It's the client that's deciding what bytes to send to Redis. If you pass it a Python object, the client will decide how to turn it into a string. It could use `str()`, it could use `repr()`, it could use `pickle`, it could use JSON, it could raise an exception, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to fire `lpush, lrange`  commands to `user['likes']` directly?? Or will that be done at application level?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast: You'd have to do it at the application level. It would be more common, though, to pull it out of the hash and into its own key so you can take advantage of Redis' data structures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain on taking `advantages of Redis data structures`? I didnt quite get what you are trying to say.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast: In your example above you're storing your list as an opaque string in a hash. It's not a [Redis List data structure](http://redis.io/commands#list), and so you don't get any of the advantages of its fast and robust implementation. If you want to be able to modify the list, you should pull it out into a top-level Redis list data structure so you can actually do the `LPUSH`, `LRANGE`, etc. that you mentioned.

Comment: I get what you are trying to say. But can I store `user['likes']` as `list` in redis hash map?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast: No, see the very first sentence of my answer.