# Don't understand why print does not display results of hmget

Tags: python, redis

I don't understand why a print does not display results of `hmget` in `redis` using python

You name it, I've tried it.

```
def newcode(R=r):
    cnt = 1
    for cnt in range(0,10):
        rec=R.hmget('rec-'+str(cnt), 'key' , 'txt')
        print(rec)
    cnt += 1
```

Here is what is returned:

```
Pipeline<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=127.0.0.1,port=6379,db=0>>>
```

I expected something like:  `1 "This is the text"` which would display the key and text values stored in the hash.

Comment: maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628455/redis-get-values-inside-a-dict-hmget/37632305#37632305

Comment: or this https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/redis/client.html?highlight=hmget

Comment: Apparently, your connection('R') is a pipeline. You need to call `R.execute()` to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

i copy your method and i prove it and work fine

```
import redis
import json


def newcode(R):
    for cnt in range(0, 2):
        rec = R.hmget('rec-' + str(cnt), 'key', 'txt')
        print(rec)

conn = redis.Redis('localhost')

user = {'name': 'username','key': 25,'txt': 'football','response': 5}
meat = {'name': 'username','key': 22,'txt': 'basquetball','response': 5}

conn.hmset("rec-0", user)
conn.hmset("rec-1", meat)

newcode(conn)
```

and the output was :

```
[b'25', b'football']
[b'22', b'basquetball']
```

Comment: Thanks all for your input.   Itamar Haber was correct, that "R" is a pipeline.
Additional code that I did not share,

 setup = """
from __main__ import pipe, rdb_connect, insert_records
"""
# from __main__ import pipe, newcode4

stmt = 'pipe(insert_records)'
print(stmt)
print(min(timeit.Timer(stmt, setup).repeat(*REPEAT)))
print     After removing the timeit.Timer function and trying the code it does work, as was pointed out, thanks!

Comment: the pipe function does do the R.execute() and that's where the results show.  It seems that when you use the timeit.Timer function that's when it doesn't work.  I researched this and found using a "Watch" command might have enabled viewing the values prior to the R.execute, but I could not get this to work.  In retrospect, I guess that is the question I'm really asking.

For now, by removing the timeit.Timer function, this works.  Thanks again for your expert assistance.